# trouble with contingency table in R

Tags: r, contingency

I looked everywhere but did not find answer to my question. I am having trouble with makig contingency table. I have data with many columns, let say 1, 2 and 3. In the first column there are let say 100 different values, in the second 20 and the third column has 2 possible values: 0 and 1. First I take just data with value 1 in column 3 (data<-data[Column3==1,]). Now I have only around 20 different values in 1. column and 5 in 2. column. However when I do a contingency table its size is 100x20, not 20x5, and contains a lot of zeros (they correspond to combination of column1 and column2 which has value 0 in column3). I would be greatful for every kind of help, thanks.

Comment: please share example data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score -1):

I guess all your three variables are factors.So convert them into character using

> as.character()

to all three variables then apply

> table()

for that.

Comment: Could you specify your problem little bit clearly... Or Could  you  explain your problem with some data and code that exists in R..??